# how to connect line and circle at border of circle

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm new to `c#` and `wpf` and I want to draw a graph . I used CappedLine.cs for edges and ellipse as nodes. I want to draw lines until they reach to circles and do not enter to the boundaries of the circles.

anyone can help me throughout this problem?
how can I detect the borders of circle?

here is my `MainWindow.xaml.cs` code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace LineCaps
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Ellipse ellipse = new Ellipse();
            ellipse.Height = 20;
            ellipse.Width = 20;
            ellipse.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
            Canvas.SetLeft(ellipse, 0);
            Canvas.SetTop(ellipse, 40);
            can.Children.Add(ellipse);

            PathFigure myPathFigure = new PathFigure();
            myPathFigure.StartPoint = new Point(10, 50);

            LineSegment myLineSegment = new LineSegment();
            myLineSegment.Point = new Point(200, 70);

            PathSegmentCollection myPathSegmentCollection = new PathSegmentCollection();
            myPathSegmentCollection.Add(myLineSegment);

            myPathFigure.Segments = myPathSegmentCollection;

            PathFigureCollection myPathFigureCollection = new PathFigureCollection();
            myPathFigureCollection.Add(myPathFigure);

            PathGeometry myPathGeometry = new PathGeometry();
            myPathGeometry.Figures = myPathFigureCollection;

            CappedLine myPath = new CappedLine();
            myPath.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
            myPath.StrokeThickness = 1;
            myPath.LinePath = myPathGeometry;

            Geometry g= Geometry.Parse("M0,0 L6,-6 L6,6 z"); ;
            myPath.BeginCap = g;

            can.Children.Add(myPath);

        }
    }
}
```

and this is my xaml code:

```
<Window x:Class="LineCaps.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:loc="clr-namespace:LineCaps"
        Title="MainWindow">
    <Viewbox x:Name="vb">
        <Canvas x:Name="can" Height="350" Width="525">

        </Canvas>
    </Viewbox>
</Window>
```

I used the CappedLine code from here:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mrochon/2011/01/09/custom-line-caps-in-wpf/

I have this result:

[image: I have this result]

But I want this one:

[image: But I want this one]

Comment: that doesn't work correctly... how about when the line is at left side of ellipse?.. then the line will reach to the bottom right side of circle

Comment: To do it right I think you need to find intersection point of your line and rectangle (using equations of line and ellipse), then just start your line from this point (now you start it from arbitrary 10,50 point).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, use mathematical method to find the intersection point between the circle and the line:

```
public Point? CalculateIntersection(Point circleCenter, double circleRadius, Point lineStart)
{
    if (Math.Abs(circleCenter.X - lineStart.X) < double.Epsilon)
    {
        if (circleCenter.Y > lineStart.Y)
        {
            return new Point(circleCenter.X, circleCenter.Y - circleRadius);
        }
        return new Point(circleCenter.X, circleCenter.Y - circleRadius);
    }
    if (Math.Abs(circleCenter.Y - lineStart.Y) < double.Epsilon)
    {
        if (circleCenter.X > lineStart.X)
        {
            return new Point(circleCenter.X - circleRadius, circleCenter.Y);
        }
        return new Point(circleCenter.X + circleRadius, circleCenter.Y);
    }

    // translate to origin point
    var translate = new Vector(-circleCenter.X, -circleCenter.Y);

    circleCenter = circleCenter + translate;
    lineStart = lineStart + translate;

    // y=kx+t -> kx1+t=y1, kx2+t=y2 
    // k=(y1-y2)/(x1-x2), t=y1-kx1
    var k = (circleCenter.Y - lineStart.Y) / (circleCenter.X - lineStart.X);
    var t = circleCenter.Y - k * circleCenter.X;

    // x^2+y^2=r^2, y=kx+t
    // x^2+(kx+t)^2=r^2  ->  (k^2+1)*x^2+2ktx+(t^2-r^2)=0
    // ax^2+bx+c=0  ->  x1=[-b+sqrt(b^2-4ac)]/2a  x2=[-b-sqrt(b^2-4ac)]/2a

    var r = circleRadius;

    var a = k * k + 1;
    var b = 2 * k * t;
    var c = t * t - r * r;

    var delta = b * b - 4 * a * c;
    if (delta < 0)
    {
        // has no intersection
        return null;
    }

    var sqrt = Math.Sqrt(delta);

    var x1 = (-b + sqrt) / (2 * a);
    var y1 = k * x1 + t;

    var x2 = (-b - sqrt) / (2 * a);
    var y2 = k * x2 + t;

    var point1 = new Point(x1, y1);
    var point2 = new Point(x2, y2);

    if ((point1 - lineStart).Length < (point2 - lineStart).Length)
    {
        return point1 - translate;
    }
    return point2 - translate;
}
```

Then, Connect them:

```
var point = CalculateIntersection(new Point(10, 50), 10, new Point(200, 70));
if (point == null)
{
    throw new Exception("no intersection between the line and the circle?");
}
myPathFigure.StartPoint = point.Value;
```